# PhoneGap 3.3.0 / iOS 7 / Status Bar and Splash Screen issue

Tags: ios, cordova

thanks in advance for your attention and the help you might give.

I would like to know if there's a way so you can init an app built with PhoneGap 3.3.0 running under iOS 7 with the status bar hidden and show it just after the splash screen is shown.

Thanks again.

PD: I'm using jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add the following code to info-plist to initially hide status bar:

   ```
   <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
   <true/>
   <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
   <false/>
   ```
2. When deviceready event is fired, show status bar:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", showStatusBar, true);

   var showStatusBar = function() {
       StatusBar.show();
   };
   ```

please refer to [status bar documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same as you. Exactly.

This is how I got rid of the status bar:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true">
        <false/>
</gap:config-file>
```

Though I don't know what you mean by "and show it just after the splash screen is shown."